# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Alticore' is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my project i am using Ajax popup control to display address details. Popup is showing perfectly For the first time page load but when i saved my details and click on the popup button it getting error like "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Alticore' is undefined".
Below is my code please help me on this.

```
function EditAddress(addressId)
{
    var companyId = $get('hdnCompanyId').value;
    var url = "AddAddressDetails.aspx?AddressId=" + addressId + "&EntityId=" + companyId   + "&EntityType=COMPANY";
    Alticore.Framework.openModalFrame('divEditAddress', url, { 'callback': addressPopupClosed, 'draggable': true, 'title': "Address Details ", 'width': '600px', 'height': '380px' });
}

function addressPopupClosed(response) // This method is called when the Popup is closed
{
    try {
        if (response.IsOk) {
            $get('btnListAddress').click();
            activeTabId = "AddressDetails";
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you link your css file and/or the js file Alticore is defined with?
something like:

```
<LINK href="Style.css" type="text/css" rel="StyleSheet">
<script src="Library.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay Dor, I didn't link Script like <script src="Alticore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>